# Find shortest vector between ray and axis-aligned three-dimensional box

Tags: geometry

I have a ray and an axis-aligned box in three dimensions. The ray is close, but not quite intersecting the box. I wish to translate the ray (not change its direction) as little as possible so that it does intersect.

In order to do so, I need to find the shortest vector from the ray to the box. In 2 dimensions, that would look like this:

[image]

If I can get that red vector, I can add it to the origin and the ray will be shifted to the box.

In 2D this is apparently relatively easy, as you can get distance between two lines, then find the smallest of the 4 lines and use that.

But in 3D I am not aware of how to do this. Does anyone know if there is a way?

Comment: the problem seems to equate to that of finding point on ray which is shortest distance from the box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the direction of the ray, what you see is an hexagon plus inner edges, which are the result of an orthogonal projection. The ray appears as a single point.

If that point is inside the hexagon, the ray already crosses the cube. Otherwise, the distance between the ray and the cube is seen as either

- a segment from the point to an edge, perpendicular to it (when the point is in a green region), or
- a segment from the point to a vertex (blue region).

[image]

You can tell if the point belongs to one of these regions by means of the equations of the lines of support of the sides and the perpendiculars by the vertices. Once you know the region, you know the closest 3D edge or vertex, and the required translation vector.

A convenient way to perform these steps is to rotate the whole space in such a way that the ray becomes the $z$ axe, then find the shortes distance in the $xy$ plane. If you need the $z$ of the point, knowing those of the vertices, you can interpolate along the edges. Finally, you can apply the inverse rotation, if needed.

Comment: This seems very helpful! Unfortunately I'm not very well versed in geometry. What does that rotation look like to make the ray into the Z axe? And would the point-point and point-segment distance tests be with the point at (0,0)?

Comment: Whoops, ignore that last part of my previous comment. If the ray is the Z axis, of course it is at (0,0). Needed to read it over a couple times for things to stick.

Comment: @TylerShellberg: you can start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_three_dimensions. The distance is with the projection of the point.

Comment: @TylerShellberg: this problem indeed requires sufficient notions of analytical or vector geometry. But if you want to tackle 3D problems (though this one reduces to 2D), there is no escape.